# Bolt CMS with Angular - how to create Angular theme

Tags: bolt-cms

I've created a custom JSON API extension for bolt and want to have a bolt theme that uses Angular, but am unsure of the best way to go about this.

Bolt would simply serve the API and a single template via a custom theme.

As far as I can see, the main issue is routing/templating. All routes other than `/bolt` need to use a single template, say `index.twig` as this will be the only template available.

Is this possible with Bolt?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to treat AngularJS vars as Twig/PHP strings ?

Like:

```
{{ "{{Angular.var}}" }}
```

You could write a Macro to smplify the process

Check the Twig docs to see how to write Macros in twig files.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#macros